# I would like to embed playlists with s3 on my Wordpress.

Tags: amazon-s3

hope all is well, question I have is I would like to embed Audio players streaming from s3?on my wordpress, each post would have a different playlist. is there a way to set this up?

Comment: I looked around didn't find exactly what I was looking for my friend sorry.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing much to be done . here are few simple steps :-

1. create an s3 bucket
2. setup the permissions for reading the objects.
3. upload the audio files to the bucket.
4. you can either use the url  ( something like http://s3.amazonaws.com//mp3_filename ) if you have not set access read to authenticated users , or you will have to pass signature , expiry date and AWSAccessKeyId as the parameters in url.
5. you might wanna try with cloudfront also, which will increase the availability and improve the performance.

on the audio player , you will have to just put the s3 uri as the source for the audio.

Comment: thanksvote thanks my friend I'm new here do not sure how I got a negative rate but this was very helpful